# fixing the gridview column width not working.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following code. I have set the `width="150px"` for footerstyle,rowstyle and headerstyle.

**Code**:

```
<strong>Title</strong><br />
        <asp:GridView ID="socGridView" runat="server"
        CaptionAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Justify"  
        DataKeyNames="id"  onselectedindexchanged="socGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
        ToolTip="Excel FIle DownLoad Tool" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">

        <RowStyle width = "150px"   BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Download" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Blue"/>
            </Columns>
         <FooterStyle width = "150px"  BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <HeaderStyle width = "150px"  BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
```

However, it doesn't work for me.Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: retagged, this is asp.net, not classic asp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that the columns width didn't change
However, after i set the gridview width, it works!
e.g.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="datasource_ssc" EnableModelValidation="True" Width="50%" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
    DataKeyNames="ssc,sales" AllowSorting="True">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
asp:BoundField DataField="vProductInfo" HeaderText="Product Info" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                            HeaderStyle-Width="200px"  ItemStyle-Width="200px" SortExpression="vProductInfo" />
```

Must be set property ItemStyle-Wrap="false"

Comment: There is one drawback for this option, this will make the column width to max

Answer (score 0):

You cant't define a row width. You can do this with the Gridview in total or with columns e.g.:

```
'Gridview Width
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100px">

'Column Width
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name (long)" DataField="Name">
            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>

'code behind
columnName.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(someDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemStyle is not working! use HeaderStyle.

```
GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderStyle.Width = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `%` instead.  E.g.,

```
<HeaderStyle Width="10%" ItemStyle Width="10%" />
```

…like this for all of the columns you have.